Heap Space exceeded in Spring Boot project
I'm encountering a heap space exceeded error in my Gradle project after updating from Java 8 to Java 17 and Spring Boot from 2.x to 3.3.2. This issue only arises on a Windows virtual machine (VM), while on my local machine, the project runs without any problems.
Interestingly, when I run the VM with Resource Monitor open, the project works fine without memory issues. But if I close the Resource Monitor, the heap space error returns.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Allocated over 7 GB of heap memory for the project.
Verified that the same code and configuration work fine locally.
Environment:
Java 17
Spring Boot 3.3.2
Windows VM
Has anyone experienced similar issues, or does anyone have suggestions on why this might happen only on the VM and why Resource Monitor affects it? Any tips on additional configurations or VM-specific optimizations would be appreciated!
i tried same project run in local , i am not facing heap space issue . but in virtual machine i am facing issue.

How many cores are assigned to the Windows VM? GC of modern Java versions expect multi-core systems so the GC runs on different core(s) than main program.

4 core Windows VM.
Using Eclipse memory analyzer tool I analyzed the dump file and found one instance of “sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl” loaded by “” occupies 19,00,04,704 (51.86%) bytes. How can this be rectified?
